# Stream mysteriously consumed twice

Tags: java, java-stream

The following code ends up with a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream.concat(Stream.of("FOOBAR"),
            reverse(StreamSupport.stream(new File("FOO/BAR").toPath().spliterator(), true)
                            .map(Path::toString)));
}

static <T> Stream<T> reverse(Stream<T> stream) {
    return stream.reduce(Stream.empty(),
            (Stream<T> a, T b) -> Stream.concat(Stream.of(b), a),
            (a, b) -> Stream.concat(b, a));
}
```

The obvious solution is to generate a non parallel stream with `StreamSupport.stream(…, false)`, but I can’t see why can’t run in parallel.

Comment: `reduce(...)` from `revers(Stream<T>)` is a terminal operation.

Comment: Yes of course, the reduce will consume the whole Spliterator, but the stream it generates from it should be usable. How come it is not consumed when producing a non parallel stream ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stream.empty()` is not a constant. This method returns a new stream instance on each invocation that will get consumed like any other stream, e.g. when you pass it into `Stream.concat`.

Therefore, `Stream.empty()` is not suitable as *identity value* for `reduce`, as the identity value may get passed as input to the reduction function an arbitrary, intentionally unspecified number of times. It’s an implementation detail that is happens to be used only a single time for sequential reduction and potentially multiple times for parallel reduction.

You can use

```java
static <T> Stream<T> reverse(Stream<T> stream) {
    return stream.map(Stream::of)
        .reduce((a, b) -> Stream.concat(b, a))
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty);
}
```

instead.

However, I only provide the solution as an academic exercise. As soon as the stream gets large, it leads to an excessive amount of `concat` calls and the note of [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)) applies:

> Use caution when constructing streams from repeated concatenation. Accessing an element of a deeply concatenated stream can result in deep call chains, or even `StackOverflowError`.

Generally, the resulting underlying data structure will be far more expensive than a flat list, when using the Stream API this way.

You can use something like

```java
Stream<String> s = Stream.concat(Stream.of("FOOBAR"),
    reverse(new File("FOO/BAR").toPath()).map(Path::toString));
```

```java
static Stream<Path> reverse(Path p) {
    ArrayDeque<Path> d = new ArrayDeque<>();
    p.forEach(d::addFirst);
    return d.stream();
}
```

or

```java
static Stream<Path> reverse(Path p) {
    Stream.Builder b = Stream.builder();
    for(; p != null; p = p.getParent()) b.add(p.getFileName());
    return b.build();
}
```

With Java 9+ you can use a stream that truly has no additional storage (which does not necessarily imply that it will be more efficient):

```java
static Stream<Path> reverse(Path p) {
    return Stream.iterate(p, Objects::nonNull, Path::getParent).map(Path::getFileName);
}
```